# Draw a line with an icon in the middle

Tags: moderncv

I'm new to \LaTeX and I'm writing my resume using ModernCV and a lot of googling.

I use the classic style and wish to make the document look a little more visual by adding icons to the section titles. For now I plan to use FontAwesome icons.

So far, I redefined the `\section` command to include a third argument (the icon/character to use).

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, color, final, roman]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvicons{awesome}
\sethintscolumnlength{3cm}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{smm}{ % third argument is [m]andatory
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}
  \phantomsection{}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
  \cvitem[0ex]{
    \color{color1} % Use the CV color
    % Left line
    \strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{
      \rule{\hintscolumnwidth - 2cm}{0.3ex}}
    % The icon
    \fontsize{.5cm}{0cm}#3
    % Right line
    \strut\raggedleft\raisebox{\baseletterheight}{
      \rule{\hintscolumnwidth - 2cm}{0.3ex}}
  }
  {\strut\sectionstyle{#2}} % Section title
}

\firstname{gnxr}
\lastname{demo}

\begin{document}

\section{Compétences}{\faWrench}
\closesection{}

\end{document}
```

The output so far is:

[image: A wrench icon next to the section title]

It looks kinda good. However, I feel like it is a hacky solution. I have no idea of the real width of the icon so all measures (2cm, .5cm) are the result of trial and error for this specific icon. The results for other characters are just wrong:

[image: A section with the letter "m" as an icon, followed by a section with the letter "i" as an icon. We can see lines are not the same width.]

Also there is a small undesired space inserted between the lines and the icon (we can notice for example that the space between the icon and the right line is bigger than with the left line).

I think a good solution would be to draw a single line instead of two, then draw the icon at the (computed) center of the line with a (fixed-width) white background. Is this the good approach? How can I do that?

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Thanks :) It should now be compilable (I use `xelatex` to process the file)

Comment: +1 just for `moderncv` (and a bit for the French). My documents with accented characters, compiled with `pdflatex`, require a slightly longer preamble.

Comment: @phollox I use `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` and I'm not sure but I think the reason I use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex` is because the former expects utf-8 by default while the latter requires a declaration

Comment: Indeed. There are several lines required to set your document. I struggled a lot with that in my first LaTeX document. For some reason, the school template was saved in Latin1 encoding, not UTF-8, and there were even more lines to make it work in `pdflatex`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\hbox` to fix a specific width, then use `\leaders` to fill the box on both sides with a line until the specified width is reached:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, color, final, roman]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale=0.9]{geometry}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvicons{awesome}
\sethintscolumnlength{3cm}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{smm}{% third argument is [m]andatory
  \par\addvspace{2.5ex}%
  \phantomsection{}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{%
    \strut\hbox to \hintscolumnwidth{%
      \color{color1}%
      \fontsize{.5cm}{0cm}\selectfont
      \leaders\hrule width-\baseletterheight height\dimexpr\baseletterheight+0.3ex\relax\hfill
      \space #3
      \leaders\hrule width-\baseletterheight height\dimexpr\baseletterheight+0.3ex\relax\hfill
    }%
  }%
  {\strut\sectionstyle{#2}}% Section title
}

\firstname{gnxr}
\lastname{demo}

\begin{document}

\section{Compétences}{\faWrench}
\closesection{}

\end{document}
```

You might notice that a lot of lines are ended with `%`. Without this TeX inserts a space there which destroys the symmetrie.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I replaced the hrules with `\leaders\hrule width-0pt depth-3pt height 5pt\hfill` (negative depth to control vertical positioning). For some reason positioning with raisebox didn't work.